# OpenCV 3 bilateral filter function error

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

When I try to use the OpenCV 3 bilateral filter function

```
bilateralFilter ( src, dst, 3, 3, 3 );
```

I am getting this error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((src.type() == CV_8UC1 || src.type()
>   == CV_8UC3) && src.data != dst.data) in bilateralFilter_8u, file /home/jean/opencv-3.0.0/modules/imgproc/src/smooth.cpp, line 3066
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'

I've already tried to fix the error by using `cvtColor(src, src, CV_8UC3);` and `cvtColor(src, src, CV_8UC1);`  but the error persists.

Any tips for solving this?

Comment: check out this line: `src.data != dst.data`. try to let your destination mat be a new one.

Comment: Looks like the problem really is the dst. I've changed it and now the problem is solved, Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as Derman said, your source and destination mat may point to the same data. You can find an example in the following link:

http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2013/10/applying-bilateral-filter.html

Another example, provided by OpenCV can be found here:

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/imgproc/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter.html